# IIS7 slow appPool startup compared to IIS6

Tags: iis-7, asp.net-3.5

I have recently purchased some new windows server 2008 boxes all running IIS7.

I have moved some of my websites across to them, but they seem to be running VERY slow when the app pool first kicks in.
All the sites are precompiled (using webdeploy) and in IIS6 they were lightening fast, I thought it might have been just because the web apps are fairly large but I get the same issue on smaller ones too.

The app pools are set to Classic mode, as we couldnt get the urlMapping to work in integrated mode.

I have seen a few posts about the slowness on the net and one post on here about it and people throwing stupid answers around such as its because your code isnt compiled or its to do with JIT, and both answers are pretty much a word that rhymes with JIT but has an extra letter. I say this because I have run much larger web apps in IIS6 and not experienced this lag.

Thanks for anything that you bring to the table on this.

edit:
just done some timings and it can take up to 28seconds for the first request to return a page...

Comment: Are your app pools setup similarly to how they were on IIS6?

Comment: They are just setup with the default settings, not changed anything from what IIS gave me.

Comment: This was slow due to using Classic Mode, I have moved it to integrated pipes which is faster at around 9seconds load time, which is still unacceptable, but I believe this is an application issue now not IIS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was slow due to using Classic Mode, I have moved it to integrated pipes which is faster at around 9 seconds load time, which is still unacceptable, but I believe this is an application issue now not IIS.